# Minimizing to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div tag, for with to minimize I am using the following JS

```
function my()
{
    $("#button").click(function(){
        if($(this).html() == "+"){
            $(this).html("-");
            $("#box, #title_bar").toggle("Up");
        }
        else{
            $(this).html("+");
            $("#box, #title_bar").toggle("Down");
        }    
    });
}
```

My div tag looks like this,

```
<div id="widnow">
    <div id="button">-</div>
    <div id="title_bar"><b>Console Log</b></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Which minimize my div to the top left corner of the page as shown in the below images,

[image: when max]

When minimized

[image: when min]

For expanding I've used, which is only expandable at the bottom,

```
#widnow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 750px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 42px;
    resize: both;
}
```

So now I want it to be like facebook chat window, i.e

1. to be minimised to the bottom of the page and
2. maximised to the original position at 250px and
3. to be expandable only at the top of the window.

How do I achieve the above tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Minimize() 
{
    window.innerWidth = 100;
    window.innerHeight = 100;
    window.screenX = screen.width;
    window.screenY = screen.height;
    alwaysLowered = true;
}

function Maximize() 
{
    window.innerWidth = screen.width;
    window.innerHeight = screen.height;
    window.screenX = 0;
    window.screenY = 0;
    alwaysLowered = false;
}

<A HREF="javascript:onClick=Minimize()">Minimize</A>
<A HREF="javascript:onClick=Maximize()">Maximize</A>
```